# How to handle package dependencies into a Qt5 CMake project?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cmake, libraries

I'm kinda stucked in a C++ Linux-based school project and i need some kind of guidance in Libraries and Packages. Please be patient since i'm newbie in these type of projects :')

I need to do a cross-platform installable game with some colleagues.

I developed a qt5 app that uses QWidget and QMultimedia. I had to install some packages to actually run the app (for example: qt5, qt5multimedia, gstreamer1.0 for audio, and probably more since i actually lost track of them). Since i need to merge this application into this school project that i'm talking about, my colleagues will have to install these packages as well (as everyone who will try to install the game, probably?).

We'll be using Cmake to build the project. This is my actual CMakeLists.txt, if anyone needs to take a look at it:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(dune LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# QtCreator supports the following variables for Android, which are identical to qmake Android variables.
# Check https://doc.qt.io/qt/deployment-android.html for more information.
# They need to be set before the find_package( ...) calls below.

#if(ANDROID)
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
#    if (ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
#        set(ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libcrypto.so
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libssl.so)
#    endif()
#endif()

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Multimedia REQUIRED)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        vistas.h
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.ui
        lobbywindow.cpp
        lobbywindow.ui
        resources.qrc
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(dune
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(dune SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    else()
        add_executable(dune
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(dune PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Multimedia)
```

What i'm trying to get is a project that has all of these dependencies in a lib folder, but i've had a hard time looking for Qt libraries online. QtCreator allows you to create Shared Libraries but my installed version doesn't have QMultimedia on the options.

• What is the best way to track these dependencies?

• Is it actually needed to do this? Should i worry about it, or just find the packages that i installed and tell my colleagues to install them?

Please tell if i came short explaining my problem or i need to specify something, thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a package manager such as [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)? It works well with CMake and the new [manifest mode](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/manifests.md) makes adding (and tracking) dependencies pretty simple since they're itemized in a JSON file at the project level. You can check to see if your project's dependencies are available [here](https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html).

Comment: On linux you should be able to use the cpack `DEB` generator which allows you to list dependencies for your package. Simply list those apt packages containing the qt libs you require. On the target system you should be able to leave the installation of the dependencies to the package manager. Anyone compiling the game will need the qt development package (qt5-dev or something similar(?)). As an alternative to listing dependencies you may be able to deploy the qt shared libraries in your own package, but you need to check the qt license to determine, if this is legal...